# Ignoring the values after decimal point

Tags: java

[image]

When I cast 175.26 in int, it returns 175,
but when I do the same with 175.0, it returns 174.

Why is it so and how to correct it? Thanks

Comment: please add your code instead of images. So others can copy paste and try in local/can directly answer without redirecting to another link.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the `diff1` value actually is 0.1749999999 . Because the IDE that you use is rounding up so you see it as 0.175, that is why you see this confusing behavior.

To check this, you could make comparison: boolean com = diff1 < 0.175;

For the exact calculation in Java, never use double or float, you could use BigDecimal instead. For example:

```
   double a  = 1.175000
   BigDecimal aa = new BigDecimal(a + ""); // has to convert to string so the big decimal does not contain any precicion lost
   BigDecimal diff = aa.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE); // get the decimal part
   BigDecimal multiply = diff2.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000));
   multiply.intValue() // 175
```

Comment: Well done for being the only respondent so far who has dealt with the "how to correct it" part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

you must know how are float and double numbers represented in binary according to IEEE 754 standard reprsentation , so you can refer to any online website like [ieee 754 standard](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ieee-standard-754-floating-point-numbers/), if you understand IEEE 754 standard, you will know that some float or double numbers like 0.175 doesn't have accurate representation , instead its representstion is estimated, this is the binary representation of 0.175 as float :

> 00111110001100110011001100110011

if you covert that number back to its corresponding float number according to IEEE 754 standard it will be :

> 0.17499999702

so it's just the matter of fact how float and double numbers are represented